# JVM Heap - Is there a way to determine how much heap a single thread consumes?

Tags: jvm, heap-memory

Is there a way to programatically (not using profilers etc) determine how much heap memory a single thread consumes? Or is there a way to set a limit on the memory consumed by a thread?

(I think this *[might](http://old.nabble.com/hg%3A-jdk7-tl-jdk%3A-4-new-changesets-td30737927.html)* be possible on Java7 though)

Comment: What do you mean? The only memory used by a thread is its stack, and the JVM operating overhead. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Tell me if my answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ThreadMXBean.getThreadAllocatedBytes(long id)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadAllocatedBytes%28long%29):

> Returns an approximation of the total amount of memory, in bytes, allocated in heap memory for the thread of the specified ID. The returned value is an approximation because some Java virtual machine implementations may use object allocation mechanisms that result in a delay between the time an object is allocated and the time its size is recorded.